# How to print lines in between two loops using list comprehension in python, to create a pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, list-comprehension

I want to acheive this
Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Whis is done with normal for loops

```py
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(1, i):
        print(j, end='')
    print(' ')
```

How can i do the same with list comprehension ? How shoud I print the empty lines in list comprehension.

I've come this far:

```py
[ print(j, end='')  for i in range(1,7)  for j in range(1,i)  ]
```

Ouput:

```
112123123412345
```

Comment: Using *list comprehension* is not the best idea, but you can unpack *generator expression* into `print()`: `print(*(''.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i)) for i in range(1, 7)), sep='\n')`

Comment: Unless you're trying to construct a list (which you do not appear to be), this would not be an appropriate use of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your string in desired format using `str.join()` as:

```
print(*[''.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i)) for i in range(1,7)], sep="\n")

# without "sep" in older versions of Python:
# print('\n'.join(''.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i)) for i in range(1,7)))
```

which will print:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: You can unpack generator expression to not build entire list in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing a space, print `\n`. This is the escape character for new line.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few methods, from simple to more advanced ...

As a simple loop adding a digit to a cumulative variable:

```
n = 0
for i in range(1,6):
    n = n*10 + i
    print(n)
```

Using sub-ranges up to the line number:

```
for n in range(1,6):
    print(*range(1,n+1),sep="")
```

Using accumulate from the itertools module:

```
from itertools import accumulate
for line in accumulate(range(1,6),lambda a,b:a*10+b):
    print(line)
```

As a recursive function:

```
def incDigit(N): return 1 if N==1 else incDigit(N-1)*10+N

for n in range(1,6): print(incDigit(n))
```